# github jira sync

Tags: jira, github

I would like Jira and Github to talk to each other so commit messages with ticket names show up in the ticket. Issue sync would be nice as well.

I know jira has a [DVCS](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.bitbucket) connector but the documentation is piss poor. From what I can tell that and the Github hooks require our private jira instance to be available from the public internet or at least github's servers. I'd only want to do this to as a last resort.

Does anyone have any suggestions on setting Jira to periodically pull the information from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End of a bad day and I had a stupid mistake:

1. Download and install DVCS
2. Add Jira as an application in one of the admin's accounts on github
3. Config a repository with the https link but drop the username@ and .git
   eg: https://foo@github.com/owner/repo.git becomes https://github.com/owner/repo

Comment: I'm still missing the port you need to forward on the firewall :(

Comment: I don't understand your last point. I'm trying to make this happen since 3 days.